# WPF - Checkbox in cell row readonly possible?

Tags: wpf

I have a ListView which is bind dynamically to a list of object of the same type.

The object have a boolean value.

There a ListView column which display a checkbox instead of the "true" and "false" normal value for that specific property.

Is there a way to set that checkbox readonly ? otherwise is there a way to tell that the click is coming from this specific row in the events "checked" and "unchecked" which execute a method in code behind ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make any control readonly by setting IsHitTestVisible and Focusable to false.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Is Valid">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsValid}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn> 
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<DataItem> data = new List<DataItem>();
            data.Add(new DataItem() { Name = "AAA", IsValid = true });
            data.Add(new DataItem() { Name = "BBB" });
            DataContext = data;
        }

        public class DataItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restyle the `ControlTemplate` of `CheckBox` to remove `RenderPressed` and bind `IsChecked` to your `DataContext` property instead of `TemplateBinding`. Here is the edited template, look for `IsChecked="{Binding MyBoolean}"` and change that to your property.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckRadioFillNormal">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFD2D4D2" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckRadioStrokeNormal">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF004C94" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF003C74" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ReadonlyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFillNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioStrokeNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{Binding MyBoolean}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"/>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place transparent TextBlock on CheckBox.
Disable CheckBox by setting "IsEnabled" fnd use the ToolTip Content on this TextBlock.
Example below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hdr" Width="34" >
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <CheckBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding IS_CHECKED}"/>
             <TextBlock>
               <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                 <ToolTip Content="{Binding TOOL_TP}"/>
               </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
         </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```